# Distributed J meter : Response from slave server is not returned to master

Tags: jmeter, client-server, rmi, distributed

I am running j meter master slave configuration in same network. 
When i remote start the server, i can see server starting and shutting down but in master there is no response under response tree or summary report.

Tried with non gui mode also but no success. It is even creating blank result file on execution. No errors are returned.

```
**"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
</testResults>"**
```

Also when i directly run the same script on j meter (normal mode) it works file.

Plesae help !!

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter removes response data from samples in distributed mode. This is by design, the idea is to reduce network IO.

If you need the data for any reason you can add the following line to *user.properties* file on all engines:

```
mode=Standard
```

The property can also be passed via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to JMeter startup script like:

```
jmeter -Jmode=Standard .....
```

References:

- [Using a different sample sender](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks but it didn't worked on updating mode=Standard .Also, I am running with only one api just to confirm the connection and response, so response is very light.

Comment: Just to verify i did a small record capture and ran the test in distributed setup(with and without mode=Standard). There i can see summary  and response tree getting created in both cases.

Comment: Consider adding `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` and `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true` properties as well

Comment: Format=xml is already there, added ...data=true but still same issue. I am running the application in VM and accessing through my system (all in same newtork). Could that be reason for any RMI port blocking ?